# "sounds fun" or "sounds like fun"

Tags: expressions

If you say, "it is fun playing golf", I think "fun" is a noun.
When I hear people say, "it sounds fun," is it a noun or an adjective?
I understand the verb "sound" is followed either by a noun or an adjective, and I think they should say, "it sounds like fun" if they use it as a noun. Or can the word "fun" be used as an adjective on its own?
Please clear this up once and for all.

Comment: _sounds fun_ does not sound correct in my ears ;)

Comment: @mplungjan- Interesting.  It's heard quite frequently in my circle of friends:  *Hiking? Yeah, that sounds fun!*

Comment: @Fujibei-  How would you classify these?  That sounds *[exciting|loud|noisy|scary|fun|dangerous...]*

Comment: Have checked the dictionary? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fun?q=fun

Comment: The use of *fun* in an adjectival sense is informal.

Comment: There is a discussion at [Wordwizard](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23591&p=79781&hilit=funner#p79781) on the increasingly acceptable use of _fun_ as an attributive adjective. With link verbs, the word class can be indeterminate (_This is dangerous_ / _drudgery_ / _fun_). After _seem_ and _sound_, one could argue for an elided particle: _He seems / sounds [like] a decent fellow_ // _That seems / sounds [like] fun_. Does it make sense to define word class on word class in an unellipted structure though?

Answer (score 1):

> Please clear this up once and for all.

On 15 April 1755, [Samuel Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Johnson) "arguably the most distinguished man of letters in English history", published his  *Dictionary of the English Language* [in order to](http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~jlynch/Texts/preface.html) "remove rubbish and clear obstructions from the paths of Learning and Genius." It is among the most influential [dictionaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_English_Language) in the history of the language. Yet it can do little to prevent people from misusing the word **fun**.

When enough people misuse a word often enough, it becomes part of the language. It can't really be prevented, no matter how many knuckles are rapped by irritable grammarians.

"That sounds **fun**!" is creeping into our language, perhaps influenced by a generation of people who want to shorten their communication to far fewer than 140 characters. Nothing can be done about it, for as Robert Burns explained,

> *The best-laid schemes o' mice an 'men
>
>    Gang aft agley*
>   An'lea'e us nought but grief an' pain,
>   For promis'd joy!

*It sounds fun* means *It sounds like fun*. Might as well adjust to it.

Behold Samuel Johnson. Does he look like a fun guy?

[image]

Comment: Looks like Blackadder has just caused him some pericombobulation.

Comment: That's not Samuel Johnson, that's @StoneyB!!  ;-)

Comment: "It sounds fun" doesn't mean "It sounds like fun", any more than "She looks fat" means "She looks like fat".

Comment: @StuartF - bullshit. And again, bullshit. Something isn’t true because you believe it to be.

Answer (score -3):

The word "fun" is a noun while the word "sound" can be either a verb or a noun. When it is used in a sentence such as " " That sounds fun." It is an error of omission resulting from the contraction of "That sounds like fun" and when we read or hear the phrase "that sounds fun" the contraction naturally "feels" uncomfortable or awkward since it is unbalanced and incomplete, unless one has been introduced to English  on "Twitter"

Comment: Many people use "fun" as an adjective. See [Do you use 'fun' as an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394806/do-you-use-fun-as-an-adjective) and the other questions linked to that one.

Comment: This is a fun game...